# Mysql Search "I" Case Insensitive

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working for a Laravel Project, and I noticed a problem. In my database (MySQL) fields stored as uppercase. When I search like below, I have a problem.

```
$query->where(function ($query) use ($q) {
    $query->orWhere('product', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%');
    $query->orWhere('stock_code', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%');
    $query->orWhere('barcode', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%');
    $query->orWhere('hs_code', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%');
});
```

For Example **FINDIK** is a Turkish Word. And when user search as **fındık** No results found.

I'm using `unicode_general_ci` for MySQL tables. And my head codes are like below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

What should I do? Some people offers MySQL `LOWER` method. But I hope there exists a better way.

Comment: some people offers or sql offers? (:-:)

Comment: Well, you can always use UPPER :-)

Comment: are you sure you are getting results with the `FINDIK`? as far as I know mysql by default is case insensitive

Comment: yes i'm getting results for FINDIK

Comment: Do you get 1 if you try `select 'FINDIK' = 'fındık';` in mysql? It will show if the problem is with Laravel or with the character set on the table

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->where(function ($query) use ($q) {
    $query->orWhere('product', 'ilike', '%'.$q.'%');
    $query->orWhere('stock_code', 'ilike', '%'.$q.'%');
    $query->orWhere('barcode', 'ilike', '%'.$q.'%');
    $query->orWhere('hs_code', 'ilike', '%'.$q.'%');
});
```

Please try to use ilike

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ilike ? or `stock_code` ilike ? or `barcode` ilike ? or `hs_code` ilike ?)' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where (`stock_quantity` > 0) and (`product` ilike %fındık% or `stock_code` ilike %fındık% or `barcode` ilike %fındık% or `hs_code` ilike %fındık%))

Comment: `ILIKE` does not work with MySQL, only PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html